# Get id of Image Template after Guest.Service.createArchiveTransaction

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using the Java-Library (com.softlayer.api) I try to create a new Image Template from a VM.
The creation works, but unfortunately, I am not yet able to know when the image is created and what is its identifier.

I use Guest.Service.createArchiveTransaction, which returns a Transaction object. But what do I know have to do with that?
I checked its content but could not find a reference to the image template being created.

Can you tell me, how I could get this information?

Below here is my code:

```
Guest.Service service = Guest.service(softlayerAdapter.getRestApiClient(), globalIdentifier);

List<Device> devices = service.getBlockDevices()
.stream().filter(device -> {
Image.Service imageService = Image
.service(softlayerAdapter.getRestApiClient(), device.getDiskImageId());

return !imageService.getMetadataFlag() && !imageService.getLocalDiskFlag();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

Transaction transaction = service.createArchiveTransaction(imageName, devices, notes);

// How do I know when the order is done and what is the identifier for the image?
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

Regards,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getActiveTransaction` method to know if transaction is still active, it return nulls when image creation was completed, this method also returns the "averageDuration"  detail you can use to estimate the time you need to wait:

```
Guest.Service service = Guest.service(client, virtualGuestId);

try {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    Transaction transaction = service.getActiveTransaction();
    String json = gson.toJson(transaction);
    System.out.println(json);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to retrieve transaction. "
            + e.getMessage());
}
```

You can use either the transaction ID retrieved from `createArchiveTransaction` or `getActiveTransaction` or the **image name** you provided to find what image template is being created.

The method `SoftLayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups` is  helpful  to retrieve  all privates images, unfortunately object-filter is not supported by Java client so you will have to retrieve all image templates and filter it using java itself.

To see the active transaction on images call to getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups using the following mask:

```
mask[id,children[id,transactionId],name]
```

It will return a structure like below:

```
{
        "id": 2029237,
        "name": "ImageName01",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2020209,
                "transactionId": 95642323
            }
        ]
    },
```

You need to match the transactionId value with the value retrieved from `createArchiveTransaction` or `getActiveTransaction`

**Java Example**

This sample retrieves all private images from account and look for the one with the same transactionId. I initialized the variable transactionId but you can improve the code and retrieve this value from `createArchiveTransaction` or `getActiveTransaction` as commented above.

Take into account that **once the transaction is completed the transactionId will be null**, so you wont be able to relate the VSI with the image through this value anymore.

```
ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);        
Account.Service service = Account.service(client);

Long transactionId = new Long(96385227);

service.withMask().blockDeviceTemplateGroups().children();

try{
    List<Group> images = service.getObject().getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for( Group img : images){                
        for(Group child : img.getChildren()){
            if(child.getTransactionId() != null && child.getTransactionId().equals(transactionId)){
                System.out.println("Image Id: " + child.getId());
                System.out.println("Image Name: " + child.getName());
                System.out.println("Image Transaction: " + child.getTransactionId());
            }
        }                
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

References:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups/

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransaction/

Comment: Hey @AlbertCamacho

Thanks for the hint. I now have the problem, that I cannot apply the mask.
I tried:

`Account.Service accountService = Account.service(softlayerAdapter.getRestApiClient());
accountService.withNewMask().privateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups()
    .id().name().children().id()
    .transaction();
accountService.getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();`
..but then I got:
Property 'privateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups' not valid for 'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group'.

Same was when I use accountService.withNewMask().blockDeviceTemplateGroups()...`` instead

Comment: Hey, I added the sample in java, I hope this help you.